# Screen is flickering when full screen in intel UHD 620

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, 20.04, fullscreen

I'm new to ubuntu. I have recently installed ubuntu 20.04 along with windows 10. Screen is flickering when videos turn to fullscreen.  Same thing happening for ppt files when in presentation mode. In windows everything is ok.

It's annoying.
Plz help.

Processor: Intel Core i5-8265U
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
[Here is the details of graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZcBE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have Lenovo T480S with Ubuntu 20.04. Playing on Intel video with VLC full screen mode - screen is flickering. As work around I turned off Tools->Interface->Show controls in full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. It is due to the change in display settings we've done before. Go to display settings and revert back the fractional scaling to 100% if it is not. It should work fine. Ubuntu version 20.04